# Partitioning a sequence into sublists

Tags: c#

This function divides a sequence into partitions, where a partition is a list of consecutive matching elements.

> Example
>
> Input: (A, A, B, B, B, A, C, C)
>
> Output: ((A, A), (B, B, B), (A), (C, C))

I've tried to make this code "obviously correct", but it still doesn't look that way to me.

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> PartitionBy<T, PK>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, PK> partitionKey)
{
    return sequence.PartitionBy(partitionKey, EqualityComparer<PK>.Default);
}

public static IEnumerable<List<T>> PartitionBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    return sequence.PartitionBy(item => item, comparer);
}

public static IEnumerable<List<T>> PartitionBy<T, X>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, X> partitionKey, IEqualityComparer<X> comparer)
{
    var itr = sequence.GetEnumerator();
    if (!itr.MoveNext())
    {
        // empty sequence was passed in, so return empty sequence
        yield break;
    }

    // Start the first partition.
    var currentList = new List<T>(new[] { itr.Current });

    while (itr.MoveNext())
    {
        var key1 = partitionKey(currentList[0]);
        var key2 = partitionKey(itr.Current);

        if (comparer.Equals(key1, key2))
        {
            // continue current partition
            currentList.Add(itr.Current);
        }
        else
        {
            // yield current partition and start a new one
            yield return currentList;
            currentList = new List<T>(new[] { itr.Current });
        }
    }

    // We know it has at least 1 element here.
    yield return currentList;
}
```

Comment: A downvote less than 5 seconds after posting?

Comment: The close-voter picked "unclear what you're asking" for a close reason; I suppose your post could use an [edit] to clarify what your code is doing, how it's used and why there are 3 overloads.

Comment: And how you mean that the code doesn't look "obviously correct"?

Comment: I think that the poster is saying that the code works correctly, but is too verbose to be intuitively understood.

Comment: @default.kramer btw there is a Linq method which handles this exact scenario from memory it is .GroupBy( x => x........) you know about it right?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon - GroupBy doesn't work because non-consecutive items end up in the same group. See my example, how one of the partitions is `(A, A)` and another is `(A)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a small point to start:

```
new List<T>(new[] { itr.Current });
```

You don't need the array too, you can just do:

```
new List<T> { itr.Current };
```

I'd suggest that you aim for consistency with your generic type names too. Why `X` vs `PK`? I'd suggest `TKey` for both.

You could do it just with a foreach:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Partition<T, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<T> items, 
    Func<T, TKey> keySelector, 
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    List<T> currentPartition = null;
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (currentPartition != null 
            && comparer.Equals(keySelector(item), keySelector(currentPartition[0])))
        {
            currentPartition.Add(item);
        }
        else 
        {
            if (currentPartition != null)
            {
                yield return currentPartition;
            }
            currentPartition = new List<T> { item };
        }
    }
    if (currentPartition != null)
    {
        yield return currentPartition;
    }
}
```

Is it clearer than your code? I'm not convinced it is.

Comment: Despite the (relative) complexity inside the loop, I do think this will be clearer for most programmers, simply because it avoids the cumbersome enumerator code that `foreach` is meant to free us from.

Comment: Yeah, I started with a foreach but it wasn't as clean as yours. I think I slightly prefer yours to my OP now. And naming it "currentPartition" is a big improvement over "currentList".